# PHP cURL POST request (JSON) sending as GET, data not showing in receiving script

Tags: php, json, curl, post, get

I've been trying to create a connection between two hosts with a POST request sent as JSON using cURL in PHP. My primary objective is to send data from Host A to Host B (labelled for clarity).

First, looking at network tools in the sender browser, the request type is always GET instead of POST, despite using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_POST. Secondly, the data is not printing/echoing in the receiving browser. However, the hardcoded outputs in the receiving script are printing in both browsers. I've tried using CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST 'POST' to no avail.

Sender JSON tab: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 59 of the JSON data

Sender Raw Data tab: {"ChangeType":"renamed","Path":"C:\File1","Param3":"Yes"}receive_jsonpost_test.php is running renamedC:\File1YesObject id #1

Code:

```php
<?php

// HOST A (sender)

header("Content-Type:application/json"); 

$testobj = array(
    'ChangeType' => 'renamed',
    'Path' => 'C:\\File1',
    'Param3' => 'Yes'
);

$url = '[redacted].edu/receive_jsonpost_test.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$payload = json_encode($testobj);
    print($payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
    print($result);
?>
```

```php
<?php

// HOST B (recipient)

print('receive_jsonpost_test.php is running ');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
print($data->ChangeType);
print($data->Path);
print($data->Param3);

print($data);
```

I know this is probably a pretty basic problem, but I'm fairly new to applied host-to-host communication and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?   Do you want HOST A  to do a GET or a POST?   When HOST B receives the request what do you want HOST B to do with the received data?  The title to your post does not correlate with your post.  What does GET have to do with this?  Why are you sending the data as json where HOST B just converts json to an object.?  Why an object rather then an array?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to interpret the response from Host A, ie...

```php
print($result);
```

as JSON, you won't have much luck since Host B does not respond with JSON. Host B's code should look more like this...

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);

// ...do whatever but no `echo` or `print`

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($someDataStructure); // now respond with some JSON
exit;
```

You should also remove this line from Host A as it too will invalidate a JSON response...

```php
print($payload);
```

---

> looking at network tools in the sender browser...

Your browser isn't making the request to Host B, PHP is. If your browser makes a GET request to Host A, then that's all it will see.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is send data to HOST B and have B echo the received data back to HOST A:

Remove this from HOST A:

```
print($payload);
```

It will send headers to the Browser.  The headers should come from HOST B response headers.

Same goes for

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
```

Again, headers should come come from HOST B response headers.

---

HOST A request:

```
$postdata= array(
    'ChangeType' => 'renamed',
    'Path' => 'C:\\File1',
    'Param3' => 'Yes'
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

HOST B possible responses

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo "$key $value\n"
}
```

OR If you want to support both POST and GET

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
  echo "$key $value\n"
}
```

**If you really need JSON:**

```
$postdata= json_encode(array(
    'ChangeType' => 'renamed',
    'Path' => 'C:\\File1',
    'Param3' => 'Yes'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

HOST B

```
header('content-type: application/json');
echo  file_get_contents('php://input');
```

OR

```
header('content-type: text/plain');
echo  file_get_contents('php://input');
```

OR

```
header('content-type: text/plain');
var_export(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);
```

If you want to do a GET request in a Browser:

```
https://example.com?ChangeType=renamed'&Path=C:\\File1&Param3=Yes

foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
  echo "$key $value\n"
}
```